# .net: Is assigning an object reference atomic (i.e. thread-safe)?

Tags: .net, multithreading

Let's say I have some variable `x` (of type `myClass`), which is initially `null` and some assignment

```
x = myObject
```

occuring *exactly once* in some background thread.

Is it guaranteed that `x` always contains either `null` or `myObject` when accessed from the main thread? Or is it possible that `x` contains some invalid data shortly?

Comment: check this article http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/06/29/multithreading-hardware-atomicity.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided the size of the type reference is the same size as the native word size of the CPU, then the assignment will be atomic (and safe in your described scenario).

In fact, (don't have the reference to hand) I'm fairly certain that a type ref will always be the same size as the native CPU word size.

Comment: Here's the reference: Partition I, Section 12.6.6 of the CLI spec states: `A conforming CLI shall guarantee that read and write access to properly aligned memory locations no larger than the native word size is atomic when all the write accesses to a location are the same size.`. Even without quoting the spec you were the first to provide a correct answer.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: not sure why you deleted your answer, it was correct after all.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it doesn't provide any additional useful information than your answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/11/22/c-3-0-object-initializers-revisited.aspx) (although it deals with somewhat different topic) I conclude that assignments *are* atomc.